# Returning a reference of an std::list element from its iterator

Tags: c++

New to C++, I've been asked to make a function in my `Matrix` class that returns a reference to the value in the spot `(i,j)`.

As part of the assignment, the class holds an `array` of `std::list` to represent the Matrix:

```
list <value_type> * m_val;
```

Which doesn't make much sense, but well, that's the assignment. I was told to start working with this:

```
template <class E>
inline E& Matrix<E>::operator() (unsigned i, unsigned j) {

}
```

This is what I tried:

```
template <class E>
inline E& Matrix<E>::operator() (unsigned i, unsigned j) {
    list<value_type> row = m_val[i];    // Get the row
    typename list< E >::iterator it = row.begin();  // Iterator at beginning of row
    for (int x = 0; x < j; ++x) {
        ++it; // For each column, I increase the iterator until I reach the desired spot
    }


    return *it;   // I'm confused here. I got my iterator in the right spot, but I am not sure how to return a reference to its value.
}
```

But as far as I can tell, this returns the value, not a reference. What I want to achieve is essentially

```
myMatrix(2,3) = 50;   // Now the value at 2,3 is 50.
```

Comment: Why do you need to *define* templates? You need only to *use* standard template containers....

Comment: You want to return a reference to an integer?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The Matrix class is supposed to hold any kind of value, I think. I'm sorry, I don't think I fully understand what you meant.

Comment: The only time it's really worth doing a `Matrix` class is when the array is 1D. I see little point in the raw pointer array of linked lists requirement.

Comment: @chris: I think my professor did say that it was pointless, but that this assignment is good for practice. He did have a Matrix with a 1D array, but then told us to make this.

Comment: Do you have to use an iterator?

Comment: @Bee: No, that's just about the only way of iterating a list I know of. Any better way is welcome!

Comment: Right. What I meant to ask was do you have to use a list, which is already answered. It's silly to use a list here but I think it's just an assignment

Comment: @Omega, It's a shame they impose pointless requirements. You won't find a single place with real code that has a requirement like that. It would be even better for learning if they could teach the concepts using examples of what you might see later when you go to work and use them. Sure learning the concepts is all good, even with code you'll never write again, but being prepared for something you might actually see and use is nice, too.

Comment: @chris: ..... you're right XD. Well, I suppose that it is nice to learn of things I'll never see though - while not practical at all, it is interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list <value_type> * m_val;`

This doesn't look good. If you're already using Standard Containers, why not use a `std::vector < list<value_type >` or `std::array < list<value_type> >`?

Apart from that:

```
template <class E>
inline E& Matrix<E>::operator() (unsigned i, unsigned j) {
    // less error-prone with bounds-checking, as Remy Lebeau stated in a comment
    if(i >= size_of_m_val_array)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("first index out of range");
    }

    //list<value_type> row = m_val[i];    // this would copy the list
    list<value_type>& row = m_val[i];

    typename list<value_type>::iterator it = row.begin();

    // less error-prone with bounds-checking, as Remy Lebeau stated in a comment
    if(j >= row.size())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("second index out of range");
    }

    std::advance(it, j);

    return *it;   // correct :) `*it` returns a `value_type&`
}
```

Bounds-checking isn't mandatory, though - just be sure to document it (and point it out!) if you don't check.

I'd rather use `E` or `value_type` consistently.

C++11 one-liner:

```
template < class E >
inline E& Matrix<E>::operator() (unsigned i, unsigned j)
{
    return std::next( m_val[i].begin(), j );
}
```

Comment: In the first example, don't forget to test `it` for `end()` before dereferencing it, in case `j` was out of bounds. Best to bounds-check `i` as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll add that to my answer, though bounds-checking isn't mandatory (e.g. Std Containers `operator[]` vs `at()`).

Comment: @DyP: when bounds-checking `j`, I would not waste time comparing it to `size()`. Just check if `advance()` results in `end()` before dereferencing the returned iterator: `it = row.begin(); std::advance(it, j); if (it == row.end()) { throw std::out_of_range("second index out of range"); } `

Comment: @RemyLebeau Since C++11, `list::size` is required to be in O(1), so I don't waste any time. If `j` is greater than `size()`, I'd end up incrementing the `end` iterator, which is UB IIRC.